# Modifying JPEG Metadata without Recompressing Image in iOS

Tags: ios, metadata, jpeg, exif, cgimage

I'm trying to use

`CGImageSourceCreateWithData
CGImageDestinationCreateWithData`

and then

`CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource`

but this discards any thumbnails or other embedded information in the original file. What I want to do is read in the file, alter its metadata, and write it out with the alterations only. But I'll settle for reading everything out of it, and putting it back again. Right now a 1.2MB image file gets converted to a 437kB file with the loss of additional data.

Is there something other than CGImage I can use? Can this even be done with the iOS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was a read-modify-write operation for image files that allowed changes but otherwise maintained unaltered data. I've determined through research and testing that this is not possible in iOS. The closest mechanism available is CGImage processing, but this only allows you to read selected information from a source image (such as image, thumbnail, properties), and then use some of that information (image, properties) to create a new destination file. There's no way to include a thumbnail in the new destination file, and no way to get around recompressing the image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is that the structure of the metadata depends upon the specific JPEG file format you are using.

You need to look at  CGImageProperties. You're going to have to make sure the properties for your specific file format get copied as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying user3344003. What I'm doing now is reading a jpeg file as NSData, creating an imageSource from that, then reading the imageProperties, making a modification, and writing those modified imagePropoerties back in their entirety. The process seems successful when I view the file externally and look at its metadata and image, but the file size gets greatly reduced. It also no longer has an embedded thumbnail.

Comment: You're going to need to copy the metadata as well. The process depends upon the file format used to store the metadata.

Comment: Image properties are the metadata, aren't they? Besides the EXIF, JFIF, TIFF, IPTC, and GPS metadata returned in the properties, what other metadata is there? Can you explain what exactly I should be looking for, and what I should do with it? The file format used to store the image is identical to the image format of the file I read. In this case JPEG. What other options beside UTI do I have to specify format?

Comment: You need to know the file format of the source files. Are they JFIF? EXIT? or Some other form of JPEG?

Comment: Just for grins, say I could somehow determined the "file format". Now what would I do with that information? What frameworks should I use? What methods should I call?

Comment: You need to look at the start of the image. If you see the text "JFIF" near the start, you have a JFIF image.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 7 you can use `CGImageDestinationCopyImageSource` "to modify EXIF and other image metadata in JPEG, PNG, PSD, and TIFF files without recompressing the image data"

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1895/_index.html